# Import cordova project in eclipse to use facebook login button

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, cordova

I am new in phonegap.

I want to use facebook login button in Android app.

So i have created cordova project and installed phonegap-facebook-plugin using CLI .

In CLI i run,

```
cordova create myApp

cd myApp/

cordova platform add android

cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID=fb_app_id --variable APP_NAME=fb_app_name
```

all this commands run successfully.

But how to import **myApp** in Eclipse.

Cordova **myApp** project doesn't have src folder why?

Please tell me steps.

I need help

Thank you

Comment: If you want facebbok login button then why don't you just download Facebook SDK and use it in your android project?

Comment: I want to use facebook phonegap SDk not facebook SDK for Android.

Comment: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md


::: ** You no longer need the additional Eclipse steps. A custom_rules.xml file was added for configuring ANT properly.

Comment: As per that document i have done all steps.but i dont knoe how to add custom_rules.xml file?

Comment: Post the code of that file here by editing your question.

Comment: <target name="-pre-compile">
        
        <pathconvert property="fixedJarsPath" refid="project.all.jars.path">
          <filtermapper>
            <replacestring from="/bin/" to="/ant-build/"/>
            <replacestring from="\bin\" to="\ant-build\"/>
          </filtermapper>
        </pathconvert>
        <path id="project.all.jars.path">
          <pathelement path="${fixedJarsPath}"/>
        </path>
        <echo message="Set jars path to: ${toString:project.all.jars.path}"/>
    </target>

Comment: <target name="-post-build">
        <move file="ant-build/AndroidManifest.xml" tofile="ant-build/AndroidManifest.cordova.xml" failonerror="false" overwrite="true" />
        <move file="CordovaLib/ant-build/AndroidManifest.xml" tofile="CordovaLib/ant-build/AndroidManifest.cordova.xml" failonerror="false" overwrite="true" />
    </target>

Comment: To import the project in Eclipse follow this link steps :http://www.pycode.com/android/creating-a-phonegap-cordova-3.0-app-in-eclipse.html then do code for facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it like this

Go to eclipse and import android project. Click **File** and choose **Import**.

[image]

Choose **Existing Android Code into Workspace** and click **Next**.

[image]

**Browse** your android project and select all. Click **Finish**.

[image]

Done!!

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/02/develop-a-simple-to-do-list-mobile-app-using-phonegapcordova-for-ios-and-android-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once. It was a problem importing the project:
I was importing with File>Import, and that wasn't working (src folder and R.java weren't being imported), so I imported with New>Project>Android>Android project from existing code and ticked "copy project into workspace", and problem solved =)